# How to get the rows which has a value greater than a number across all columns in excel sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am newbie to the excel formulas.I have an excel sheet which has lets say 100 rows and 100 columns. columns have different values from 0 to 20. I want the rows where any of the column value is greater than 10.

How to ignore the hidden columns, if these are in the range, without modifying the range? I mean based on some IsHidden kind of property?

Comment: Help on Excel formulas should go into SuperUser. StackOverflow is meant for VBA programming questions or very complex formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
=IF(MAX(A1:C1)>10,"Greater",IF(MAX(A1:C1)=10,"Equal",IF(MAX(A1:C1)<10,"Smaller")))
```

**Image:**

[image]

**New Version as per request:**

```
=IF(MAX(A1:B1,E1:F1)>10,"Greater",IF(MAX(A1:B1,E1:F1)=10,"Equal",IF(MAX(A1:B1,E1:F1)<10,"Smaller")))
```

Comment: what if I want to ignore few columns in the range? Lets say 100 columns and I dont want to apply this formula on column B and D.

Comment: @viveknuna see edited version. You just change the range to cover using ","

Comment: Thanks Perfect :)

Comment: I have one more question. Does this formula applied on hidden columns also?

Comment: if you use their range yes!

Comment: then how to ignore the hidden columns, if these are in the range, without modifying the range? I mean based on some IsHidden kind of property?

Comment: Is there any way to get the column names which has the greater value then the number?

Comment: Details such as wanting to ignore hidden columns should go into the original question. Entirely new questions like getting column names should be asked as separate questions. There are solutions to automatically ignore hidden cells in formulas, but that needs to be the question to get people answering it.

Answer (score 2):

Something simple like:

[image]

Formula used in `F1`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:E1,">10")>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: what if I want to ignore few columns in the range? Lets say 100 columns and I dont want to apply this formula on column B and D.

Comment: You don't need to use IF statements to return TRUE/FALSE... just use the result of the comparison itself: =COUNTIF(A1:E1,">10")>0

Answer (score 2):

If you have data in 100 columns from A to CV, put this at the top of an empty column (CW1) and fill down:

```
=MAX(A1:CV1)>10
```

Comment: what if I want to ignore few columns in the range? Lets say 100 columns and I dont want to apply this formula on column B and D.

Answer (score 0):

You can't automatically ignore hidden columns in formulas, but you can automatically ignore hidden rows. If you transpose your data, using Copy > Paste Special, you can use this formula to test the maximum value ignoring hidden rows:

```
=AGGREGATE(4,5,A1:A100)>10
```

To understand the first two parameters, you can look at the help on the AGGREGATE function, or you can type out the function manually to get pop-ups lists that explain the options.